# What is mean of "not explicitly being listened" on manual page of inotifywait?

Tags: inotify

man inotifywait:

> delete_self
>       A watched file or directory was deleted. After this event the file or directory is no longer being watched. Note that this event can
>   occur even if it is not explicitly being listened for.
>
> unmount
>       The filesystem on which a watched file or directory resides was unmounted. After this event the file or directory is no longer being
>   watched. Note that this event can occur even if it is not explicitly
>   being listened to.

How to understand mean of "that this event can occur even if it is not explicitly being listened" on that manual page?

https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/inotify-tools/inotifywait.1.en.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you can get these events even if you used the `-e` option and didn't specify them. For instance, if you use

```
inotifywait -e modify filename
```

and the file is deleted, you'll get a `delete_self` event, even though you only asked for `modify` events.

This means you need to check the event type in the output, even if you only requested a specific event.

Comment: Thank you ,but really I need check output ? non-specified event seem is hide on output as Gilles said and I tested that.

Comment: If you don't check the output, you have to check the exit status, as he pointed out.

Answer (score 3):

When you ask inotifywait to wait for an event (i.e. not in `--monitor` mode), and you specify one or more event types (with the `--event` option), it normally doesn't exit until that particular event occurs. For example:

```
$ touch foo
                                    $ inotifywait -e access foo
                                    Setting up watches.
                                    Watches established.
$ echo >>foo

$ cat foo
                                    foo ACCESS 
$                                   $ echo $?
                                    0
                                    $
```

(The two columns represent separate terminals, with blank lines inserted to make the events come out in chronological order.) Here, after the watch on `foo` is established, there's a MODIFY event, but since the event filter on the `inotifywait` doesn't include MODIFY, nothing happens. The `inotifywait` command only returns later when an ACCESS event happens.

Now suppose the file is deleted while it's being watched for access.

```
                                    $ inotifywait -e access foo
                                    Setting up watches.
                                    Watches established.
$ rm foo
$                                   $ echo $?
                                    1
                                    $
```

Removing foo triggers a DELETE_SELF event. The `inotifywait` command sees this event. It doesn't print it, because it was told to only report ACCESS events. But `inotifywait` exits: it did count the event even though it wasn't in the filter. The command exits with status 1 to indicate that “an event occurred which was not being listened for” (and wasn't ignored as most non-watched events are).

Comment: Thank you. but I tested your example that `echo >>foo` also triggers a `ACCESS` event ?

Comment: @illiteracy It shouldn't, and I can't reproduce this.

Comment: I just try guess for this,maybe this is something of shell(as such some  shell option or other shell thing)?my shell :`GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)`,I'm not know if any shell option maybe is about to this.